# Query to sum applications per week from a date column in new columns (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to sum the applications per week over a given year. The dataset consists of a record for each application. It has a date field formatted as `2014-01-01 00:10:12.143`

I would like to find a way, any way, to sum the number of records for each week number (thus displaying 52 weeks, each with the number of applications that week). I am using the query below to create a week and year field. However, now I don't know how I can condense this down to a weekly number. Any help is appreciated!

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(ww, Applications_UrlRefferer.CreatedUtc) AS AppWeek,
    DATEPART(yyyy, Applications_UrlRefferer.CreatedUtc) AS AppYear, 
    *
FROM 
    Applications_UrlRefferer
WHERE 
    (CreatedUtc BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-01-01 00:00:00', 102) 
    AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-11-30 00:00:00', 102))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a way to do it:

```
SELECT DATEPART(ww, AP.CreatedUtc) AS AppWeek,
    DATEPART(yyyy, AP.CreatedUtc) AS AppYear,
    COUNT(*) ApplicationsPerWeek
FROM Applications_UrlRefferer AP
WHERE AP.CreatedUtc BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014/01/01', 111)
                        AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014/11/30', 111)
GROUP BY DATEPART(ww, AP.CreatedUtc)
ORDER BY DATEPART(ww, AP.CreatedUtc)
```

If you happen to need the query to return data for more than one year (from October to March, for example), you must use these two at the end:

```
GROUP BY DATEPART(yyyy, AP.CreatedUtc), DATEPART(ww, AP.CreatedUtc)
ORDER BY DATEPART(yyyy, AP.CreatedUtc), DATEPART(ww, AP.CreatedUtc)
```